# SSIS Using Variables in Query Name

Tags: ssis

Let's say I have the following scenario

```
Select
      age
     ,address
     ,full_name
from
     [dbo].customers
```

I want to replace the `[dbo]` part with an ssis variable, so when we go to run this package and need to replace the schema, it's a piece of cake.

What I have tried so far was creating a SQL variable, named `schema_var_name`, and appending it to the front, but this is not working out for me.

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong?

Here is what I have:

```
"Select
      age
     ,address
     ,full_name
from
     '@[User::schema_var_name]' + '.[customers]' "
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to concatenate the `@[User::schema_var_name]` variable within the SQL text, with the other parts of the query enclosed with double-quotes (`"`).  An example of an expression for your SQL command is below.  This can then be used as the expression for a variable that is set for the source statement in an Execute SQL Task or source component within a Data Flow Task.

```
"Select age, address, full_name from " +  @[User::schema_var_name] + ".[customers]"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also build a dynamic sql statement and execute it in an `Execute SQL Task`. The `?` tells the task that you want to use a variable in that location. You then set up the variable under `Parameter Mapping`. Your query would then look like this:

```
DECLARE @schemaName NVARCHAR(100) = ?
DECLARE @sqlQuery NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'
SELECT
      age
     ,address
     ,full_name
FROM
     [' + @schemaName + '].customers'

EXEC(@sqlQuery)
```

EDIT:

Here's what the Parameter Mapping would look like:
[image: Parameter_mapping]

The `Parameter Name` is most often the least intuitive of these fields. It's a 1-based id sequence for `Input` parameters. If you had another input variable to use, its `Parameter Name` would be `2`.